# xcode scm failure: conflict with [username].mode1v3 package file

Tags: iphone, svn, xcode, version-control, conflict

I get this error in realtion to my [username].mode1v3 package file:

> Error: 155015 (A conflict in the
>   working copy obstructs the current
>   operation) Description: Commit failed
>   (details follow):

I can do a compare from the SCM results menu on this file. Doing so reveals 102 conflicts (differences) between my local copy and the latest version in the repository. Problem is I don't understand what this file relates to or how to fix it. Differences occur in the file under keys like

> PBXSmartGroupTreeModuleColumnWidthsKey

which I have no idea about.

I am the only one working on this project. How is it possible to resolve a conflict such as this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're probably working on two computers?

Any conflicts that happen in that file can safely be ignored - just tell your SCM to accept your local version.  It's one of the files Xcode uses to keep track of your project state within the IDE.

I'd recommend taking it out of source control and telling your SCM system to ignore it.

Comment: great, thanks. how does one tell SCM to ignore this file on future commits? is it as simple as deleting the file from the repository?

Comment: not sure if this was the right thing to do but, to fix it I ended up deleting said file from repository. I was then getting a different error for that file: Error: 160013 (Filesystem has no item) Description: File not found. So, i deleted the said file from my local xcode package. this allowed me to committ. but when i added it back in (haivng coied it prior to this), I was getting the same error. I copied said file, deleted my working dir, and checked 
out another working copy. all good now it seems. Strangely, *.mode* was already added to my global-ignores in.subversion.config throughout all

Comment: If you're using SVN, you can try something like:

svn propedit svn:ignore

And adding the file name.  Google for svn ignore for more help.

Answer (score 1):

This file contains your personal Xcode settings (like window positions and so on). It should not be under version control at all.